# Gorm Association with transactions

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to do a transaction which requires some preloads, but it does not seems to work.

count is working fine though.

I have tried the following with preload and association, but neither seems to work.
Is it possible to do this in one transaction, or do I need to go into more raw sql?

```golang
tx := db.Begin()
    if tag != "" {
        var tagModel TagModel
        tx.Where(TagModel{Tag: tag}).First(&tagModel)

        if tagModel.ID != 0 {
            tx.Model(&tagModel).Association("BookModels").Find(&BookModel{})
            count = tx.Model(&tagModel).Association("BookModels").Count()
        }
    }
err = tx.Commit().Error
```

structs:

```golang
type BookModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    Tags        []TagModel     `gorm:"many2many:book_tags"`
}
```

```golang
type TagModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    Tag        string      `gorm:"unique_index"`
    BookModels []BookModel `gorm:"many2many:book_tags"`
}
```